# (SPOILER: Big Bang Theory) How does this shirt Sheldon wearing, depict the Doppler effect?

Tags: doppler-effect

This image of Sheldon wearing the shirt is from Season 1 Episode 6 of the Big Bang Theory sitcom.

[image: Season 1 Episode 6]

He goes on to demonstrate the Doppler Effect. But I don't see it. I tried thinking of it as a spherical object moving away from the observer. I am not satisfied with that explanation. Was I right? The images I find of the doppler effect on the internet often have waves spaced differently, but never with different thicknesses as in Sheldon's shirt.
I hope it is appropriate to ask about it here.

One other answer I received: "An application of this is exoplanetary detection, which utilizes barycentric shifts of a star interpreted as the star’s light slightly shifting in wavelength." If that is right, can someone elaborate.

Comment: you don't need "spoiler alerts" on 16 year old shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. Dot depicted on the shirt can be a spherical wave source moving away from the observer. Typical Doppler effect illustration looks like this :

[image]

, i.e. source is moving perpendicular to the line-of-sight of observer. However, typical human does not walk side-ways, like a crab. Instead, we walk forwards or backwards,- in this case collinearly to the picture viewer line of sight. So for being able to differentiate between forwards and backwards motion, we need some specific markers of wavefront(s) which are closer or more away from us. Waves which are closer to us,- are depicted with thicker lines and these farther from us,- depicted with thinner lines.

Or it may simply be that lines getting thicker just re-inforces idea that it is a radial movement (not perpendicular one) to the observer, because these markers adds "3D perspective".

Anyway, we can see that waves which are closer to us,- have bigger spacings between them and waves which is closer to the source,- are with smaller gaps. Hence, we conclude that wave source is moving away from us radially. (In my given picture observer would be fixed at coordinates point $[-10,0]$)

Comment: Can you give an example for the radial movement and explain why that is not perpendicular?

Comment: I gave an example of perpendicular movement Doppler effect,- in this picture you can see that waves on the right side of moving object is more densely packed, while waves on the left side - more sparse. While in the given movie picture,- right and left wave front sides of source is symmetrically spaced (no asymmetry as in perpendicular movement). Hence actor must be moving in a radial away from observer.

Comment: Can you please define perpendicular to what, and define radial movement. My understanding says the radial movement is the perpendicular movement

Comment: In perpendicular movement object is moving perpendicular to the line-of-sight of observer, like in given Doppler effect picture- object is moving in $x,y$ cartesian plane, while our line of sight is along $z$ axis, which is perpendicular to $x,y$ plane. Preferably observer's coordinate $z \gg 1$, so that moving object's angle to the our line of sight would not much deviate from $\pi/2$. Meanwhile if you would like to watch a radial movement (relative to you),- object must move collinear to your line of sight. In given picture, your location would be at $z=0,y=0$ and somewhere along $x$ axis.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not what was intended, and indeed there may not be a single meaningful answer, but this reminds me of [gravitational redshift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_redshift). Gravitational redshift arises naturally from the usual Doppler effect, combined with the [equivalence principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle). The circle in the middle is a massive object (e.g. a planet) from which electromagnetic waves are being emitted. The farther away from the source the observer, the longer the wavelength they measure. I don't think the wave "crests" getting thicker represents anything but the waves getting stretched, i.e. the wavelength getting larger, but I could be wrong.

[image]
([image credit](https://sites.google.com/site/salamcosmology/research/relativistic-effects-on-lss))

I could see this depicting a source moving away you, the observer, the spacing between the crests therefore appearing smaller close to the source just by virtue of being farther away from the observer, but then this doesn't seem to visualize the Doppler effect specifically, only a source moving away. The spacing increasing as you look away from the source doesn't really correspond directly do an increasing wavelength.